# How to Automate Copying Files From a Remote Computer?

Tags: windows, automation, copy

I am working on a remote computer that has a very restricted network, it doesn't allow driver mounting, has no internet acess, and so on.

I can only copy files to my local computer using the converntioal way of copy and paste (press ctrl C on the file in the remote computer and then press ctrl V in my local coputer).

Is there a way to automate this process in windows? I need to keep copying files for a couple of days.

Answer (score -1):

Can use mstsc that should be the intranet. Consider FTP Server?

Comment: The only way to access the server is via RDP that’s in a PAM webpage. It’s highly restricted, as copy and paste works fine for me, I’m wandering if there’s a way to automate this process.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.